# Create dynamic form with inserting form data in websql using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create dynamic form with Javascript, once form create than all the data should submit using websql in the database. Here is my code for creating element dynamically.

Note: (able to make form, but then how to create column dynamically for data insertion) any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add(type) { //Create an input type dynamically. var element = document.createElement("input"); //Assign different attributes to the element. element.setAttribute("type", type); element.setAttribute("value", type); element.setAttribute("name", type); var tab = document.getElementById("fooBar"); //Append the element in page (in span). tab.appendChild(element); var linebreak = document.createElement("br"); tab.appendChild(linebreak); }
</script>

<body>
    <form>
        <h2>Dynamically add element in form.</h2> Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
        <br/>
        <select name="element">
            <option value="button">Button</option>
            <option value="text">Textbox</option>
            <option value="radio">Radio</option>
            <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
            <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
            <option></option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h3> Form </h3>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <span id="fooBar"></span>
        <br/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var db = openDatabase("User", "1.0", "applicant data", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to create a table and insert data into it

```
var db = openDatabase("my.db", '1.0', "My WebSQL Database", 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
    });


var insert = function(firstname, lastname) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)", [firstname, lastname]);
    });
}
```

```
insert('FirstName' ,' LastName');
```

Comment: thank you @shrey gupta , but my problem is how many input field user has create basis on that want to create table.